# Launching ECS service from our own AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to deploy my sample Spring Cloud Microservice into AWS ECS service. I found that Fargate method and EC2 launch method. Here actually I am looking for to launch ECS service from my own EC2 instance. Now I have only Ubuntu 16.04 AMI. I am  planning to use AWS ECS optimized AMI as my EC2. So I need to launch ECS using my own EC2. So I am confused about the launching by optimized my own EC2.

I am seeking useful links or documentation for launching using above method. Since I am beginning stage on AWS Cloud.

Comment: Have you read the official guide at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create_cluster.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMI you've configured for your instance doesn't matter (generally). Once your EC2 instance is created, go over to the ECS section of AWS and create a cluster containing your host.

In ECS you need to define a task containing your container, the repo to pull it from, and all the other necessary details. From here you can go to your cluster and launch your task on your host, either manually, or by defining a service to automate the launching for you.

Comment: I find myself looking at this question, with a related one: how to use encrypted EBS for ECS. Setting choice of AMI would facilitate this.

Comment: How to do this via CLI?